# Yogic liberation like raising kundalini vs Bhakti path

Tags: vishnu, vedas, krishna, puranas, yoga

I read that by raising kundalini the serpent power to crown chakra , one can attain state of samadhi , which leads to liberation.

My question is , how exactly this liberation compares with 6 type of liberations(like sarupya , sayujya etc) mentioned in vaishnava scriptures?

Comment: The type of liberation discussed in the Yoga school is known as Kaivalya, and it's also the same type of liberation striven for by followers of Advaita.  I discuss the Sri Vaishnava view of Kaivalya here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6686/36 You may also be interested in my question here, which relates to the six types of liberation: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6943/36

Comment: Thanks . According to link you described  kaivalya is equivalent of sayujya , where in people have the same experiences as Vishnu.

Comment: No, Kaivalya is equivalent to Ekatva, as I discuss here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6686/36 See this book for a good description of the Sri Vaishnava view on the difference between true Moksha or Sayujya vs. Kaivalya: https://books.google.com/books?id=8TwHhuZrZ-wC&lpg=PA147&ots=kI4puW89qt&dq=desikan%20kaivalya%20sayujya&pg=PA147#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Basically, it boils down to this: in Kaivalya, you attain realization of your own Atma.  Now if Advaita were true, that would be enough to attain Brahman, because in Advaita the Jivatma and Paramatma are one and the same.  But in Vaishnava philosophies like Visishtadvaita, they're not the same, so just because you realize your own Atma doesn't mean you get Brahmanubhava or the experience of Brahman.

Comment: Thanks. But what exactly you meant "realization" here? . Ramadas who was guided to self realization by ramana maharishi said that "everything in the world is rama".

Comment: By self-realization I mean full knowledge of your own Atma.  Now according to Advaita, which is the philosophy that Ramana Maharishi believed in, Brahman (i.e. Vishnu) is everything and the individual Atma is identical to Brahman.  So Advaitins believe that self-realization, i.e. fully understanding your own Atma, is sufficient to attain Brahman.  But the six types of liberation you're talking about are concepts in Vaishnava philosophy, where the Jivatma and Brahman are different, so attaining full understanding of your own Atma is not sufficient to attain Brahman.

Comment: So Vaishnavas believe that Ramana Maharishi and his followers attain the Ekatva form of liberation, but not the higher forms of liberation.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Would have been better if the comments were your answer, so that it is easily available for others. Those links in the comments are good. It's a request :-). Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

**Kundalini raising and uniting it with Sahasrara Chakra is one of the very easiest way to get Mokshya.** It mostly exists in hidden form in our texts, it is because Gods (devatas) do not want us that we achieve salvation easily as cited in Brihadaranyaka Upanishad(1.4.10) also cited in the starting of Shiva Gita in Padma Purana.

**_______________________________________**

Although it is in hidden form in all our texts. But still we can get direct information about it by the grace of great Acharyas like Adi Shankara, Guru Gorakhnath, Mahavatar Babaji, Ramakrishna Paramhamsa, Swami Vivekananda and others.

Adi Shankaracharya also told uniting Kundalini Shakti from Muladhara to Sahasrara chakra is same as being uniting with Brahman. Here is an excerpt from Traditional Shankara Digvijaya:

> Shankara Digvijaya Canto 12
>   
>   (25-37) Then the Acharya reached the temple of Mookambika of great spiritual power, which was surrounded by a dense and attractive growth of trees and plants like mango trees, jack trees, palms, pomegranates, sugar cane and the like. With eyes brimming with tears of bliss and with all the hairs on end, that great sage
>   Sankara, possessed of the spirit of universal benevolence, recited the following hymn in praise of the Divine Mother with a heart
>   overflowing with devotion: "0 Mother! It is the three hundred and sixty rays of light proceeding from Thy lotus feet that reflect 
>   all through the year as the light of the sun, the moon and the fire. Men versed in Thy worship according to the ritualistic code adore Thee with sixtyfour proceedures of worship and with rich offerings including costly garments. Others worship Thee with non-material offerings. **They offer Thee worship with these sixtyfour procedures
>   in the six psychic centres along the Sushumna path.** Ordinary people worship Thee with material offerings; middling devotees with mental offerings followed by physical offerings; and great ones with spiritual worship only. But when one is established in Non-dual Consciousness, no question of worship or adoration
>   arises. Thou hast thirty eight aspects, of which five lead to liberation. Wise men always adore Thy feet which excel every other aspect. As the fire of cosmic destruction, Thou bumest up the
>   universe; as life-giving ambrosia, Thou createst the worlds; and as the soul of immortality, Thou preservest it and redeemest the Jivas. Those who contemplate Thee in these three aspects attain spiritual felicity. Those who want to adore Thee first grasp the truth about Thee from the instruction of the Guru, then realise it in Samadhi, and attain to the state of Non-duality. **Those who meditate on Thee in the lowest Chakras, known as Muladhara and Swadhisthana, are prompted by worldly desires and attain only to them.** Those who adore Thee in Manipura just reach the gate of Thy spiritual being. Those who meditate on Thee in the Anahata-chakra, attain to Thy region; those who do so in the Visuddhi-chakra attain closeness to Thee; and those doing 'so in the Ajna-chakra attain to equality of bliss with Thee. **The highest type of Sadhakas who meditate on Thee in the thousand-petalled lotus in the head, known otherwise as Dhruva-mandala, overcome the interest in the four forms of communion and attain to oneness with Thee.** These four forms of communion are: the unity of Sri Chakra and the six Chakras in the body; the unity of the Mantras pertaining to the Sri Chakra and the· six Chakras; the unity of Sri Chakra and Thyself; and the unity of the Mantras of Sri Chakra and Thyself. The Sadhaka recognises all these forms of unity."

Thus as Adi Shankara tells "attain to oneness with Thee"... Thus denoting we become Brahman by that.

**______________________________________**

Guru Gorakhnath in his Hatha Yoga Pradipika states that those who have awakened kundalini obtains ParamPadam (Highest state)

> Suptā ghuruprasādena yadā jāgharti kundalī 
>   Tadā sarvāni padmāni bhidyante ghranthayoapi cha ।।2।।
>   
>   **When the sleeping Kundalinî awakens by favour of a guru, then all the lotuses (in the six chakras or centres) and all the knots are pierced through.**
>   
>   
>   Prānasya śūnyapadavī tadā rājapathāyate 
>   Tadā chittam nirālambam tadā kālasya vañchanam ।।3।।
>   
>   Susumnâ (Sûnya Padavî) becomes a main road for the passage of Prâna, and the mind then becomes free from all connections (with its objects of enjoyments) and 
>   Death is then evaded.
>
> Śaktimadhye manah krtvā śaktim mānasamadhyaghām 
>   Manasā mana ālokya dhārayetparamam padam ।।54।।
>   
>   **Placing the mind into the Kundalini, and getting the latter into the mind, by looking upon the Buddhi (intellect) with mind (reflexively), the Param Pada (Brahma) should be obtained.**

Thus one gets united with Brahman when Kundalini is awakened and gets united to Sahasrara chakra.

**______________________________________**

Great Yogi Rama Krishna Paramhamsa also told the same:

> Gospel of Ramakrishna 
>   **Awake, Mother! Awake! How long Thou hast been asleep In the lotus of the Muladhara! Fulfil Thy secret function, Mother: Rise to the thousand-petalled lotus within the head, Where mighty Shiva has His dwelling; Swiftly pierce the six lotuses And take away my grief, O Essence of Consciousness!**  [Page no. 267]

**_____________________________________**

Swami Vivekananda in commentary of 1.34th Patanjali Yoga Sutra says:

> One they call Ida, another Pingala, and the third Susumna. Pingala, according to them, is on the right side of the spinal column, and the Ida is on the left side, and in the middle of this spinal column is the Susumna, a vacant channel. Ida and Pingala, according
>   to them, are the currents working in every man, and through these currents, we are performing all the functions of life. **Susumna is present in all, as a possibility; but it works only in the Yogi.**

In the commentary of 2.50th Sutra he says:

> By place is meant that the Prana is held to 
>   some particular part of the body. By time is meant how long the Prana should be confined to a certain place, and so we are told how many seconds to keep on motion, and how many seconds to keep another. **The result of this Pranayama is Udghata, awakening the Kundalini.**

**--------------------------------------------------------------------------**

Thus one gets united with Brahman when Kundalini pierces the Sahasrara chakra. It is same as being one with Brahman. **If you take it as being same with Shiva residing in Sahasrara with Saguna aspect then it is equivalent to Sayujya mukti. If you have theory of duality ie, Jiva can never be Brahman then such type of Mokshya is equivalent to Ekatwa ie. just united with Atman not Brahman.. Thus it depends on your belief about the type of Mokshya yogi get from this type. If Non Dualism is right then person is united with Brahman and hence mokshya is eternal and if Dualism is right person is united with his Atman only [ie.Ekatwa] thus is non-eternal.**

**_____________________________________**

For the location of 7 chakras in our body one doesn't require hidden meaning of scriptures also. One can get direct knowledge by Pratakshya Praman (ie. Direct Perception)..

> The place where solid waste comes is associated with solidity (ie.Bhu tatwa) thus  named as Muladhar.
>
> The place where liquid waste (Jala tatwa) comes in our body is located just above it. Thus that area named as Swadhisthana .
>
> Above it is the place where Agni tatwa causes digestion in our body thus Manipura is named in that area.
>
> Above it is the place where Vayu tatwa is in our body.( ie. Lungs is there). Thus that area is named as Anhata.
>
> Above three chakras are related to Akash tatwa each goes on being more subtler on going above. First sound produced from vocal chord which is element of Akash tatwa, that area named as Vissuddha. Then light perceived in the eye area named as Ajna. And the most subtlest which even transcends Akash Tatwa is pure consciousness thus that area named as Sahasrara chakra.

Thus these 7 chakras are the representation of elements from below ie Bhu tatwa, Jala tatwa, Agni tatwa, Vayu tatwa and Akash tatwa and thus finally transcending the Akash tatwa too. Thus Mokshya happens when Kundalini shakti goes on transcending these Panchamahabhuta. Thus the location and function of each chakra can be directly perceived by direct perception....

Comment: Thank you very much for excellent answer. But I  am not sure , whether it answers my original question.It does not answer , whether there is any difference between moksha achieved through yogic liberation with that of liberation mentioned in vaishnava scripture. One such answer  by keshav deals with that

Comment: @sysinit I have told it in second last paragraph look there...

Comment: @Tezz You can add Skanda Purana Chapter "Tandava of Shankara" where Chakras are described though Kundalini is not mentioned.

Comment: @The Destroyer oh thanks.... can you give me a link or pdf page for that chapter....

Comment: Tezz can you expand on "thirty eight aspects, of which five lead to liberation"

Answer (score 2):

Whatever the holy scriptures says about the types of liberation or enlightenment or Moksha, the sine qua non force behind every liberation is Kundalini itself without which enlightenment is impossible irrespective of the path one chooses.

So rousing of Kundalini whether consciously,subconsciously or spontaneously happens when the body is fit and ripe for its ascension.

Ramakrishna Paramahansa says that real spiritual knowledge cannot arise if Kundalini is not roused. Wama says it that without the awakening of Kundalini, liberation is not possible. Tailanga has stated that the rousing of Kundalini leads to yoga(union with the Brahman). Shankaracharya himself was an accomplished yogi in Kundalini Yoga. Arawinda has called Kundalini the divine force.(source: Laya Yoga by Shyam Sundar Goswami).

Comment: Your profile says you are kundalini activated. Would you mind sharing how this activation happened and if it is fully activated? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the asking@moonstar. It all happened 3 years back when I tried to search for better meditation practices for my anger management, I stumbled upon Kundalini Yoga by Sri Swami Sivanand. Enthralled by K’s powers soon I started to wake up at 4 o’cLock and do my sadhana consisting of various pranayama techniques. By the call of the Grace or may be due to previous life’s sadhana, after 4 months of practice and one fine morning, while I’m doing kapal bhati, a sudden surge of electric current sparked in my left calf and I heard a popping sound at my scrotum.

Comment: Scared to the core, I tried my best on the internet, to find ways to stop its ascension, and finally learnt that its impossible to stop K’s awakening except by some high masters. For the first 6 months, I have undergone what in the west they call Kundalini Syndrome or spiritual emergence. During this period I experienced various minor Sidhis, and with the help of KSN (Kundalini Support Network) a yahoo group, I learnt how to manage Kundalini by surrendering to the Shakthi rather than resisting It.

Comment: And as for the full awakening, no it’s not. I’m a K awakened person but not a fully blown Kundalini person. For this, one need a living Guru.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Would you mind stepping into https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75552/k